# Converting data symbology from Fill to Marker

Tags: qgis, symbology, point-in-polygon, markers, fill

I'm new to QGIS and can't seem to find any way to convert data from "Fill" to "Marker" I have some data that I would like to overlay on a basemap as Markers which vary in size depending on the size of the data for each point. I can't find information on how to do this anywhere.

Comment: Have you consulted the official QGIS documentation?

Comment: this should help : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html?highlight=symbology#ls-symbology ; if you are still stuck after reading that, update your question by telling us where you are stuck